# Contains return the first element whose text has only a part of given string

Tags: dom, cypress

My question is about assertions on a table. I am trying to find an element with certain text, in this case the text is a date-time string.

The problem occurs when using `contains`.

[image: example]

If I write `cy.contains('td', '04/01/2023 08:00').parent()` and then `cy.contains('td', '04/01/2023 16:00').parent()`, when the DOM looks like this

[image: example2] &

[image: exemple3]

T query for first element work just fine, but for the second one Cypress finds the element is not visible and then `.parent()` sends it to the first element.

So pretty much `contains` returns the first element that has a part of the given string.

Any ideas how this could be solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to do an exact match on the text you want by using a `.filter()` command.

```js
cy.get('td').filter((index, td) => td.innerText === '04/01/2023 16:00')
  .parent()
```

Or use the parent row directly

```js
cy.get('tr').filter((index, tr) => tr.innerText === '04/01/2023 16:00')
```